# Globally-generated property of vector bundle and the tautological bundle on its projective bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is my question which seems trivial:

> Let $X$ be a projective manifold with a vector bundle $\scr{E}$ on it. If $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}(1)$ is generated by global sections, whether the $\scr{E}$ generated by global sections or not? If not, is there some easy counterexamples? In which special case we have this property? Here $\mathbb{P}(-)$ is in the sense of Grothendieck.

Note that we let $f:\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})\to X$, then $f_*\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}(1)\cong\scr{E}$. If we have $0\to\mathscr{K}\to\mathscr{O}^{\oplus N}\to\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}(1)\to0$, then we have
$$0\to f_*\mathscr{K}\to f_*\mathscr{O}^{\oplus N}=\mathscr{O}^{\oplus N}\to f_*\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}(1)=\mathscr{E}\to R^1f_*\mathscr{K}\to0.$$
We don't know whether $R^1f_*\mathscr{K}$ is zero or not.

---

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that
$$
H^0(X, \mathcal{E}) \cong 
H^0(X, f_*\mathcal{O}(1)) \cong 
H^0(\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}), \mathcal{O}(1)).
$$
Next, observe that the evaluation morphism for $\mathcal{O}(1)$ factors as
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}), \mathcal{O}(1)) =
H^0(X, \mathcal{E}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})} \to f^*\mathcal{E} \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)
$$
through the evaluation morphism for $\mathcal{E}$ and the tautologocal morphism (which is surjective).

Now, if $\mathcal{E}$ is globally generated, its evaluation morphism is surjective, hence so is the evaluation morphism for $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

On the other hand, if $\mathcal{E}$ is not globally generated, its evaluation morphism is not surjective, hence there is a point $x \in X$ and a vector $0 \ne e \in \mathcal{E}_x$ which is not in the image of the evaluation morphism of $\mathcal{E}$. Then it is clear that the evaluation morphism of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is not surjective at the point $[e] \in \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}_x)$, hence $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is not globally generated.

Comment: Thank you very much!